# How to add custom classes to admin list table default rows or columns?

Tags: admin, columns, wp-list-table

I usually add columns to admin tables for various tasks. This time I'd like to keep defaults but add classes to them. Is it possible in some way? I took a look to available filters and to the WP_List_Table class, but I didn't find anything usefull.